# Should I use prototypes decorator or there is another way?

Tags: javascript

I have some code for example. I need to add the logging function to the "fn" function of "Test" class. At the same time it should work as the original function without changes (accept and return the same values), but additionally display "call" in the console. I cannot change the original "Test" class function or the created object. The code can only be written in the designated area. As a result, when I call console.log after "End of code" I should see both the result and the specified "call". Is it possible to do? Can you help or give advice how i can do it?

```
class Test {
  constructor(num) {
    this.num = num;
  }

  fn(...numbers) {
    const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
    return this.num + numbers.reduce(sum);
  }
}

// Сode here

// End of code

const mytest = new Test(5);
const result = mytest.fn(2, 3, 4);
console.log('Result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the function on `Test.prototype`:

```
const original = Test.prototype.fn;
Test.prototype.fn = function(...args) {
    console.log("Log the call here");
    return original.apply(this, args);
};
```

Live Example:

```js
class Test {
  constructor(num) {
    this.num = num;
  }

  fn(...numbers) {
    const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
    return this.num + numbers.reduce(sum);
  }
}

// Сode here
const original = Test.prototype.fn;
Test.prototype.fn = function(...args) {
    console.log("Log the call here");
    return original.apply(this, args);
};
// End of code

const mytest = new Test(5);
const result = mytest.fn(2, 3, 4);
console.log('Result: ', result);
```

Note the way I call the original, using [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) in order to set `this` to the correct value.